# 1 of my builds on Jenkins fails with this error 'NullPointerException'

Tags: jenkins, build, nullpointerexception

So I have a number of jobs on Jenkins, but the final job seems to fail and produces the code below. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
Started by user Anthony
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/GIST-Deploy-To-Production/workspace
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hudson.plugins.build_timeout.BuildTimeoutWrapper$1EnvironmentImpl.<init>(BuildTimeoutWrapper.java:106)
at hudson.plugins.build_timeout.BuildTimeoutWrapper.setUp(BuildTimeoutWrapper.java:120)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:154)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:584)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using Build Timeout plugin.
Your build is timing out.

Either increase the timeout in the plugin, or fix the cause of the timeouts